# How do I ensure only Region Monitoring capable devices can see my app in the store?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, location

Apple's [Location Awareness Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html) suggest to include the `location-services` and possibly the `gps` for `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities`.

My app requires the [Region Monitoring APIs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html%23//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CLLocationManager). How do I ensure only capable devices can see my app in the store?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right, location-services and gps will allow devices other than the iPhone 4 to install your app. You could pick some other feature though that you know is iPhone 4 exclusive, like camera-flash or gyroscope and require that one.

I'm not entirely sure whether apple will frown upon a restriction without an apparent need, however gyroscope appears to me like a likely restriction in a navigation enabled app. If you try this approach, I'd explain things in the text field for the comments to the reviewers. Another caveat would be that you'd risk that a future device wouldn't "fit in" - an hypothetical iPhone mini which would feature region monitoring but lacking a gyroscope or camera flash wouldn't be able to install your app, for example.

To be entirely honest, If I were you, I'd ask apple to make sure.

Comment: Since Region Monitoring and Significant Location Change APIs both use cell tower monitoring, the method I use is to specify "telephony" in the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities dictionary. This will effectively restrict the app to iPhones only (devices that can make calls). Less arbitrary than the other ways of excluding unwanted devices since it correctly communicates the device requirement - cellular capability.

Comment: @JonGrall The iPhone 3GS has telephony, but no region monitoring, so you can't use that as a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities - Apple Developer Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html). Basically exactly what you said. Are you looking for instructions on how to do that?

Comment: No, I know that I where to do it (my Info.plist) but since I don't think location and gps exclude all the devices they need to. I think region monitoring is only available on iPhone 4. (Even though 3GS/3G support iOS 4, they don't support region monitoring)